# jQuery ID selector not working

Tags: jquery, variables, selector

I'm sure this is really simple, but I'm having problems with it.

I have the following jQuery operations which don't seem to be working:

```
$("img[id='Char_2']").attr("src", "http://image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800e");

$("img[id='Char_" + Character + "']").attr("src", "http://image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800d");
```

I'm testing it: http://jsfiddle.net/PottyMonster/M6ZqD/

What is the solution?

Comment: have you tried $("img[id=Char_" + Character + "]").attr("src", "http://image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800d");

for some reason SO changes "); to ;); in the end of the line above.

Comment: Why aren't you using a normal id selector (`$('#Char_2')`)?

Comment: Sometimes, depending on the chars in your IDs, or if you're stuck working on someone's garbage markup over which you have no control, that form of ID selector is necessary. I always use it with this manner of quoting, though: $( '[id="theId"]' ) If none of that works, you need to verify your document contains what you think it contains, and that the dynamic selector is being built the way you expect.

Comment: $("img[id=Char_" + Character + "]").attr("src", "[image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800d"](http://image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800d%22)); could not recreate refer [meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83837/157949)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not where you think it is.  It's not in the ID, but rather, your `onClick` was never called.

Here's a working example, written unobtrusively:

```
jQuery('img').click(function(){
    var s = $(this).attr('id');
    s = s.slice(s.length-1, s.length);
    ChangeTo(parseInt(s));
})

function ChangeTo(Character) {
    $("img[id='Char_2']").attr("src", "http://image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800e");

    $("img[id='Char_" + Character + "']").attr("src", "http://image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800d");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use just the id selector (I don't see why you wouldn't, ids are unique in the page), you could use

```
$("img#Char_2").attr("src", "http://image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800e");

$("img#Char_" + Character).attr("src", "http://image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800d");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with this jsfiddle.net (alpha). With Firebug you will see that the debugger says

> ChangeTo is not defined

So, it has nothing to do with jQuery or JavaScript.